# ClassLoader definePackage example

Tags: java, class, package

I am currently creating a custom ClassLoader for my application, I have the class loader loading the class files, but there is no package been added to the classes

I know that ClassLoader has a definePackage() that lets you add the package to the file as it is being loaded but i cannot find any examples of this online, I am trying to use the following but it is not working for me

```
definePackage(name, "", "", "", "", "", "", url);
return defineClass(name, classBytes, 0, classBytes.length);
```

does anyone know how to do this using definePackage()?

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#definePackage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.net.URL%29) is the API for ClassLoader definePackage()

Answer (score 0):

It appears this information is normally included in the manifest of the jar. Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html

As for your particular usage, `URLClassLoader` does the same thing except with nulls in place of empty strings, unless a manifest is present, so yours is probably fine:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/URLClassLoader.java#261

However, you're using the class name for the package name, which isn't going to work. The lookup is in `Class.getPackage()` and looks like:

```
static Package getPackage(Class<?> c) {
        String name = c.getName();
        int i = name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i != -1) {
            name = name.substring(0, i);
```

You can see it strips off the class name. This means you'll need to `definePackage` with the package rather than the class name. You'll also need to ensure you don't define a package more than once. All together it would look something like:

```
private static void yourMethod() {
    String packageName = getPackageName(name);
    if (packageName != null && getPackage(packageName) == null) {
        definePackage(getPackageName(name), null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}

private static String getPackageName(String className) {
    int i = className.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (i > 0) {
        return className.substring(0, i);
    } else {
        // No package name, e.g. LsomeClass;
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to solve a similar problem, and found this a little interesting. Apparently it *is* the responsibility of the `ClassLoader` subclass to make this call: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076054/core-java/create-a-custom-java-1-2-style-classloader.html